# JavaScript: Does a long method name slow down the program?

Tags: javascript, performance, performance-testing

Is it possible that a long method or variable name slows down your javascript program a bit?

I wanted to ask because I am currently working on a program where i have a very long method identifier and I wonder if I should shrink it. It would however make my code not so clear anymore.

I know it doesn't matter for compiled languages but what about javascript?

P.S. I do not plan to use a minifier.

Comment: have you tried on jsperf.com?

Comment: It seems it's currently out of service.

Comment: I do not know about run/processing time but it will increase download time of the file.

Comment: How long is your function name?

Comment: about 80 characters, I would definitly agree with IMTheNachoMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, function name length, variable name length, etc, should have no bearing on performance, unless you're talking name length in hundreds of thousands of characters.